# After solving f(x) by Laplace transform, how to find the conditions for the solution to be a bounded function？

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

The question is to find the conditions (about constant $a, b$) for $f(x)$ to be a bounded function. $f(x)$ is a solution of the IVP
$$f''+f=\sin(bx), ~~ f(0)=a, ~f'(0) = 0$$

I solved the function (using Laplace transform) and I get the solution:
$$f(x) =
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{cl}
-\frac{1}{2}x\cos x+\frac{1}{2}\sin x+a\cos x,& b=1 \\ 
\frac{1}{2}x\cos x-\frac{1}{2}\sin x+a\cos x,& b=-1 \\ 
\dfrac{b\sin x-\sin(bx)}{b^2-1}+a\cos x,& \text{others}\\
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
Then I found that when $b = 1$ or $b = -1$, the function is not bounded.

Is that all? I did not understand the intent of the question. Is there any limitation in Laplace transform that influences the solution to be unbounded?

Comment: The unbounded nature of the solution does not come from the Laplace transform - it comes from the differential equation's own resonance. Normally the homogeneous solution is "killed" by the differential equation, but when it still exists to the right after supposedly being "killed" then it must be "bigger" than what we expected in some sense.

Comment: @NinadMunshi What does 'bigger' than expected" mean ?

Comment: @mask, your solution is correct. You may also get the expressions at $b=1$ and $b=-1$ just disclosing the uncertainty in the third formula (put $b=1+\epsilon$ and $\epsilon\to0$). At $b=+-1$ you get a resonance: the frequency of external power coincides with the own frequency of the system - the vibration amplitude in this case increases indefinitely